# Increasing UIButton size temporarily on touch

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Im creating an app which has 10 buttons and each has an `IBAction` to go into the next view. What I want is that on touch the size of the button increases till the user does not take his finger away. Also on double tap the `IBAction` is called.
 Now the question is should I use gestures for this ?

One solution is to change the buttons into imageviews and then use their methods in the gestures. But I want to keep the buttons likewise .... 
Any solution would be appreciated.  Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the image of the button on touch .

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"enter-hover.png"] forState:U UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: I'm just worried that the button's 'center' will be preserved, or it will scale from the top-left corner. Haven't tried...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2)` then users put his finger on the button to avoid dupliction of images in your app (if it matters).. And make it back to (1.0, 1.0) then removes it. All can be done using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget%3aaction%3aforControlEvents%3a)

Comment: Unless he doesn't want to upscale pixel-perfect images. Should work 100% perfect for RoundRect buttons, though.

Comment: My buttons are custom made with images so will this affect them ?

Comment: Try and see. If you will resize pictures with big scale numbers (like make it 2 times bigger) you will see some pixel-mess. Also it depends on quality of source image. I think about using bigger images only, because upscaling makes more artifacts then downscaling (not sure, but it seems to be so). Easiest way is to check it on display.